# I have an issue: expected but identifier found and compilation aborted

Tags: pascal

I will do an exam tomorrow, but now I can't run it, can anyone help me?? Thanks!!

```
program v2

uses 
  crt;

var 
  t, dongia: real;

begin
  clrscr;
  write('nhap t='); readln(t);

  if dongia >= 100000 then 
    t:= 70 / 100 * dongia;

  writeln('in don gia:'t);
  readln;
end.
```

Answer (score 1):

- Add a semi colon (;) after the program name (so v2;)
- Add a comma between the string literal and "t", so (  'in don gia:',t )
- as Roy says in the comments, the logic of your program is wrong.  Dongia is uninitialized before the check.

Next time, add a problem description including errormessages and show that you spent some effort/thought in finding the problem.

Comment: it is still that problem: ")" expected

Comment: On which line? Please be specific.

Comment: if (dongia>=100000) then t:=70/100*dongia; <== this line

Comment: oh now it has been fixed. Sorry guys :D but my result was 1.40000E+05

Comment: The only reason I can think of to get that particular error is that 100000 would not be recognized as a valid real number...

Comment: You probably had to change the entire program, right? Because the code as it is would just print whatever the user entered in `t`.

Answer (score 0):

Put parentheses around the IF condition:

> if (dongia>=100000) then

and you should also put a comma in the writeln:

> writeln('in don gia:', t);

Comment: Edited... BTW if would help if you were more specific, for instance, you could say on which line you got the syntax error. That would also help *you* to understand where you made the error.

Comment: You are probably confused with languages that have C-like syntax, Pascal does not require parenthesis there.